# session variables not stored with reroute

Tags: fat-free-framework

After a successfull login of a user, I store his/her credentials in SESSION (session is stored in a postgreSQL db) and then use $f3->reroute to the page I need the user to go depending on the credentials. that part works fine.

In the target page, I open a session, with the intent of checking the user's credentials  but there are no session variables stored.

I should add that I am refactoring this application and before the session variables where working fine, so I know this is not a problem with the session variable storing / reading per se, I have got a feeling that it is somehow linked to my usage of reroute but I can't pinpoint it

Any ideas ?

Comment: Do you reroute to the same domain? Have you checked if the session is stored *before* rerouting?

Comment: yes, reroute is to the same domain; As far as I can tell yes the session data is stored.

Comment: I have worked around this issue when I realised that reroute was making a round trip to the client (I thought it was self calling) by re arranging my code.